# Is it possible to develop a Ti iOS module that employs a framework only built for the device?

Tags: ios, module, titanium, xcode4.5

My module builds successfully, but I tried to use the module in Titanium Studio and install directly to the device. I got the same type of "SystemExit: 65" error that happens when the module test harness build fails. Of course, I can't use the test harness because a framework the module uses is only built for the arm architecture / not i386.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rip out i386 support from the generated project and the build scripts. Then run from Xcode yourself. You're on your own, though. A better bet would be to get a binary with i386 included.